# How to get the barcode width?

Tags: python, pdf, barcode, reportlab

I need to put a barcode 128 on the bottom right of an A4 size PDF with `reportlab`, with a margin of 5mm.

For this we need to get the actual width of the barcode before using `drawOn` on the canvas.

**How to get the width of a reportlab barcode, after it's created?**

Note: I tried with barHeight and barWidth but the latter doesn't give the full width of the barcode, but only the smallest distance between two bars, more or less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When doing:

```
barcode = code128.Code128(ID, barHeight=1 * cm, barWidth=1.5, quiet=False)
```

then simply `barcode.width` gives its width :)

Indeed `Code128` is a subclass of the class `MultiWidthBarcode` which itself is subclass of `Barcode` which has the property `width` defined [here](https://github.com/mattjmorrison/ReportLab/blob/master/src/reportlab/graphics/barcode/common.py#L106):

```
def width(self):
    self._calculate()
    return self._width
width = property(width)
```

---

Then, here is how to place a barcode on bottom right corner of an A4 sheet:

```
MARGIN = 0.5 * cm
barcode.drawOn(c, 21 * cm - MARGIN - barcode.width, MARGIN)
```